# ASP.Net jQuery webcam image to database varbinary(max)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I've written Javascript that captures images from a webcam and then I'd like to serialize it to my SQL Server database. The field in the database is the usual varbinary(max). I can see from firebug that the **raw image** is being passed to my web method, but it keeps throwing the following error:

"Insert of '797719006-' failed: Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.sql.SQLException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Picture', table 'GoldStar.Students.Pictures';

The javascript that captures the image definitely works just fine, so I know there's no problem there, it's just a matter of saving it to the database. Perhaps I'm over-complicating things by updating with a web-method via ajax???

I've created a web-enabled method on my registration page and it looks like this:

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static void UpdatePicture(object picture)
    {
        //Check if the user already has a picture in the database.
        using (var dataContext = new DAL.GoldStarModel())
        {
            var userPictures = (from p in dataContext.Pictures
                                where p.UserId == (Guid) Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey
                                select p);

            if (userPictures.Count() > 0)
            {
                //If user already has a picture then update.
                userPictures.First().Picture = picture as byte[];
            }
            else
            {
                //If User does NOT have a picture then add one.
                dataContext.Add(new Students.Pictures()
                                    {
                                        UserId = (Guid) Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey,
                                        Picture = picture as byte[],
                                        CreationDate = DateTime.Now

                                    });
            }

            dataContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The relevant Javascript is as follows:

```
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                var profilePic = $('#profilePic')

                $('#webcam').hide();

                try {
                    //Update the profile picture in the parent.
                    var currentPic = self.parent.document.getElementById('MainContent_UserFormView_RegisterUser_StudentPicture');

                    var oldWidth = Number(currentPic.width);
                    var oldHeight = Number(currentPic.height);

                    currentPic.src = canvas.toDataURL();

                    currentPic.width = oldWidth;
                    currentPic.height = oldHeight;

                    profilePic.show();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Account/Register.aspx/UpdatePicture",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: "{'picture': '" + currentPic.src + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (result) {
                            //ApplyTemplate(result)
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Have you walked through your code on the server side with a debugger? Offhand, it looks like the cast from Object to byte[] is failing.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly where it's failing. That's the problem, I can't seem to figure out how to serialize the javascript HtmlImageElement or the raw image data (currentPic.src) to a byte[] for storage in the db. I've googled, but haven't come across anything relevant yet. The safe cast I'm doing to byte[] was just a stab in the dark and breaks much as I figured it would.

Answer (score 1):

have you used something like fiddler to check what's going over the wire, because at first glance, it's only the string path to the image, not the image data.

On the server you can't just cast from an object to a byte array, unless you've already got a byte array, in which case use that as the type. Again from your code, it's unlikely jquery is passing a binary array of data to your method.

I suspect you'll need something like Silverlight or Flash to upload the image data. The html sandbox is very tough when it comes to sending file data to the server.

**Update**

You'll need to parse the string. You have everything you need, which is good. You'll need to look for where the base64 string starts. Take that base64 string & use Convert.FromBase64String which will give you a byte array that is your image. Store this in your db.

I'd change your webmethod to accept a string, because that's what is being generated by the canvas. All should work.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Firebug to see what's going on in the background. If you look carefully, .src in this case is not a string path to the image, as it's being set to canvas.toDataURL(), which looks like: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEU..." and I have absolutely no idea how to do something meaningful w/ that.